# jQuery live() alternative

Tags: jquery, validation, webforms, live, blur

When an input is empty I want it to have a red outline (so users know that he missed the field).

When the input is not empty - there should be no outline at all.

The problem is, the outline appears only after I leave the input empty **and click somewhere else**.

Just try to erase #input and **don't click**.

http://jsfiddle.net/qUJ7K/

Changing live() to blur() doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `keyup` which indicates a key press that checks the input field every time you press a key.

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fKT5q/).

More information on keyboard events:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Answer (score 0):

Use `bind` with `keyup`.

```
var $el = jQuery("#input");

$el.bind('keyup', function() {
    if ($el.val() != '') {
        $el.css('outline', '0');
    } else {
        $el.css('outline', 'solid 5px red');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qUJ7K/1/